The date picker format stopped working after I moved the code from the PHTML file to a separate JavaScript file
I was implementing a date picker on one of my pages, and it was working fine. However, after moving my JavaScript files from the PHTML file to a separate JS file, it stopped working and is now picking the wrong format. Can you help me fix it?
Working file that present in the same phtml file
 $('#imported_from_dated').datepicker({
    format: '<?php echo DATE_PICKER_FORMAT; ?>', // format 'yyyy-mm-dd'
 }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
   $('#searchDataForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'imported_from_dated');
   if ($('#imported_to_dated').val() != '') {
     $('#searchDataForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'imported_to_dated');
   }
   $('#imported_from_dated').show();   
 });

 $('#imported_to_dated').datepicker({
   format: '<?php echo DATE_PICKER_FORMAT; ?>', // format 'yyyy-mm-dd'
 }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
    $('#searchDataForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'imported_from_dated');
    $('#searchDataForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'imported_to_dated');
    $('#imported_to_dated').show();
 });

 $('#searchDataForm').formValidation({
    message: 'list message',
    fields: {
        imported_from_dated: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'error message 1',
                },
                date: {
                    format: '<?php echo DATE_VALIDATION_FORMAT; ?>', // format MM/DD/YYYY
                    message: 'error message 2',
                }
            }
        },
        imported_to_dated: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'error message 3',,
                },
                date: {
                    format: dateValidationFormat,
                    message: 'error message 4',,
                },
                callback: {
                    callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
                        var startDate = $('#imported_from_dated').val();
                        var endDate = $('#imported_to_dated').val();
                        if (startDate !== '' && endDate !== '') {

                            var dateSt = startDate.split('/');
                            var dateEd = endDate.split('/');
                            var StDt = Date.parse(dateSt[2] + '-' + dateSt[0] + '-' + dateSt[1]); //Year, Month, Date
                            var EdDt = Date.parse(dateEd[2] + '-' + dateEd[0] + '-' + dateEd[1]);

                            if (StDt > EdDt) {
                                return {
                                    valid: false,
                                    message: 'error message 5',
                                };
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).on("keyup",'[name="imported_from_dated"]',function() {
    $("#searchDataForm").formValidation('revalidateField', 'imported_from_dated');
}).on("keyup",'[name="imported_to_dated"]',function() {
    $("#searchDataForm").formValidation('revalidateField', 'imported_to_dated');
});

from the above code while i am selecting any date it will update in to MM/DD/YYYY format.
example : 09/05/2024
But i have move the js file in to seperate file and the code looks like this
PHTML file
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var dateFormat = '<?php echo DATE_PICKER_FORMAT; ?>';
    var dateValidationFormat = <?php echo DATE_VALIDATION_FORMAT; ?>;
 </script>

 JS file

 $('#imported_from_dated').datepicker({
   format: dateFormat,
}).on('changeDate', function (e) {
    $('#searchDataForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'imported_from_dated');
    if ($('#imported_to_dated').val() != '') {
        $('#searchDataForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'imported_to_dated');
    }
    $('#imported_from_dated').show();
});

$('#imported_to_dated').datepicker({
   format: dateFormat,
}).on('changeDate', function (e) {
    $('#searchDataForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'imported_from_dated');
    $('#searchDataForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'imported_to_dated');
    $('#imported_to_dated').show();
});


$('#searchDataForm').formValidation({
    message: 'list message',
    fields: {
        imported_from_dated: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'error message 1',
                },
                date: {
                    format: dateValidationFormat, // format MM/DD/YYYY
                    message: 'error message 2',
                }
            }
        },
        imported_to_dated: {
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'error message 3',,
                },
                date: {
                    format: dateValidationFormat,
                    message: 'error message 4',,
                },
                callback: {
                    callback: function (value, validator, $field) {
                        var startDate = $('#imported_from_dated').val();
                        var endDate = $('#imported_to_dated').val();
                        if (startDate !== '' && endDate !== '') {

                            var dateSt = startDate.split('/');
                            var dateEd = endDate.split('/');
                            var StDt = Date.parse(dateSt[2] + '-' + dateSt[0] + '-' + dateSt[1]); //Year, Month, Date
                            var EdDt = Date.parse(dateEd[2] + '-' + dateEd[0] + '-' + dateEd[1]);

                            if (StDt > EdDt) {
                                return {
                                    valid: false,
                                    message: 'error message 5',
                                };
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}).on("keyup",'[name="imported_from_dated"]',function() {
    $("#searchDataForm").formValidation('revalidateField', 'imported_from_dated');
}).on("keyup",'[name="imported_to_dated"]',function() {
    $("#searchDataForm").formValidation('revalidateField', 'imported_to_dated');
});

I have verified that the values are being passed to the JS file correctly, but I'm still getting the date in the '2024-09-05' format (not converting to MM/DD/YYYY format). I can't figure out what's causing the issue, even though the code inside the JS file is written within the document.ready function.

Is the code inside script tags? Is the code possibly executed before the page has been loaded? $(function() { /* run the code on page load */})

Have you first of all tried to log dateFormat to the console, from within the document.ready handler inside your external script file?

The code present inside $(document).ready(function () { }) function. also verified in the console.log. values are coming correctly
